# store file as bytes[] in db2 using java

Tags: java, jpa, db2

I am using open JPA (websphere application server) to store files in db2 column. The JPA entity looks like:

```
@Lob
@Nullable
private byte[] content;
```

Storing the file in the database using apache fileupload

```
FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
byte[] fileData = item.get();
attachment.setContent(fileData);
manager.updateAttachments(attachment);
```

Retrieving the file:

```
ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
byte buff[] = new byte[8192];
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);

response.setHeader("Content-Length",String.valueOf(uploadedFile.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                    + uploadedFile.getName() + "\"");
int i = 0;
while ((i = input.read(buff)) > 0) {
    op.write(buff, 0, i);
    op.flush();
}
```

I tried uploading an image file. When retrieving it, firefox displays the following error:
The image "http://localhost:9081/SampleFormServlet/retrieveFileServlet" cannot be displayed, because it contains errors.

Can somebody please point to an example that does something similar?

Comment: Where did you set the content-type?

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison. I did not paste the right code. I was not writing the complete byte[] to op. It works fine now. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you post your code as a sample?